# How to populate a list with the data from a textfile?

Tags: java

Basically I have a file which prints the details of a transaction. I have to retrieve the account ID, the amount and the date and put it in a list. 
So far I cannot retrieve the necessary information and put it in a list.

The file looks likes that  :

```
Transaction on account 00000007: amount 50, dated Tue Dec 06 15:54:35 GMT 2016
```

So I have to retrieve 00000007, 50 and the date and put it in a list. This is where I am stuck.

Here is the list :
    `private List<Transaction> pendingTransactions, completedTransactions;`

So far here is the code I have:

```
 public void loadPendingTransactions()
{
    try {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(new File("pendingTransactions.txt"));
        String content; 

        while((content = scnr.readLine()) != null) {
            String arr[] = content.split(" ");
            int amnt[] = content.split(" ");
            String accID = arr[4];
            int amt = arr[6];
            String date = arr[7];
            pendingTransacrions.add(new Transaction(accID, amt, date));
        }
        scnr.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("We're sorry, we are unable to find that file: \n" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("We're sorry, we are unable to find that file: \n" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please improve the question: what problems is this code having? What does the text file look like? What do your debugging efforts show you, such as use of a debugger or println statements?

Comment: I edited my question, is it good enough now ?

Comment: Again, what problems are you having? And can you be more specific with your question? It currently reads like a work request. The main issue is: at what specific step are you stuck?

Comment: You should specify the issues you're currently having, rather than "get this to work" :-)

Comment: Hovercraft I edited again, I hope I was more specific.

Comment: And looking at your code closely - it doesn't compile. You can't get an int amount by spliting a string. You need to do appropriate conversions first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the file line by line and match every line to the same regular expression. For each match create a new transaction object and add it to a list.

```
package org.example;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TransactionLoader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String pathToFile = "transactions.txt";
        TransactionLoader loader = new TransactionLoader();
        List<Transaction> transactions = loader.loadTransactions(pathToFile);
        System.out.println("\n\nResults:\n");
        for(Transaction t : transactions) {
            System.out.printf("Transaction ID: %s, amount: %s, date %s%n", t.id, t.amount, t.date);
        }
    }

    private List<Transaction> loadTransactions(String pathToFile) throws Exception {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^Transaction on account (\\d+): amount (\\d+), dated (.+)$");
        List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToFile));
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                if(matcher.matches()) {
                    Transaction tx = new Transaction();
                    tx.id = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1));
                    tx.amount = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
                    tx.date = new Date(Date.parse(matcher.group(3)));
                    transactions.add(tx);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Line does not match: " + line);
                }
            }
        }
        return transactions;
    }

    private static class Transaction {
        public long id;
        public int amount;
        public Date date;
    }

}
```